# What is the name of the conjugation of "to be" in "Have him be here on time"?

Tags: conjugation

"The good parents have their kids *study* French"
"You're not going to make him *eat* those veggies"

Is that simply the infinitive? Or is it imperative? Or subjunctive? I've been seeing this form around but I can't quite peg the tense/mood.

Comment: I don't know about " to be" but whole sentence pattern is called as the causative form.

Comment: Infinitive. *Have him (to) be here on time*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the infinitive. It has no tense/mood. The grammatical form, i.e. tense/mood/person/number, is assumed by the main verb.

> The good parents ***have*** their kids study French.
>
> The good parents ***would have*** their kids study French if they had the money. (conditional)
>
> I ***had*** my kids study French. (past)
>
> ***Have*** your kids study French! (imperative)

Comment: _Have `X` `InfinVP`_ is one of several special constructions with auxiliary _have_. One is a causative construction: _I had them rotate my tires when they changed my oil_ means I caused the rotation by telling them what to do. The other is an adversative construction: _I had somebody slash my tires when I parked in the alley_ means that the tire-slashing happened to me, not that I caused it. These both occur in the passive: _I had my tires rotated; I had my tires slashed._

Comment: @JohnLawler: So, are you saying that because it can occur in the passive, it is not the infinitive?

Comment: No, there is a missing infinitive _be_ in the passive; that's one of the funny things about these particular idioms, and how one can tell they're idioms.